# How to add a marker to a Raphael 'paper' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael, double-click

I need a marker that behaves much like adding a marker to a map. On double click cause a marker to be displayed at the point that was clicked, and returns the x/y pixel coordinates of the point that was clicked.

I have Raphael paper:

```
var R = Raphael("paper", 500, 500);
```

with paths (`R.path("M 92.3456 ... 37.0934 Z")`) on it that defines shapes. And I have to be albe to add markers on this paper with shapes.

I am not a javascript programmer so I don't really even know where to start. So any help here is much appreciated!

Comment: Didn't you find the answer useful? Have you been able to use it with your shapes? Bye!

Comment: Yes I have used this function. But instead of shape I have used .image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've made this simple fiddle to help you with your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/mN5du/1/

I just add a Raphael doubleclick event to the circle (you can do the same with your paths). When this event is fired up, stores the mouse coordinates in two variables. Then I just use those two variables to draw a new circle. If you want to draw a path instead of a circle, you just need to use the variables within the path coordinates.

I hope this works for you! If you have any questions just tell me! bye!

**Edit:** Look at the commentary Below, is a good contribution to the answer!

**Edit2:** The line `console.log(x,y)` Its there to print the mouse values in the browser console, it's not necessary for the code to work.

Comment: You might want to use a framework (like jquery) to make your script cross-browser compatible as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/gfE6g/) - your example works in IE, but not firefox

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Fiddle is just ilustrative of how you can achive the markers placing with raphael and JS. Thanks for the correction I think that its going to be useful for complete the answer.